# How to call gazebo_msg/GetLinkState service for a sensor mounted on a robot?

Tags: gazebo-camera, gazebo-sensor

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I have the following problem:

To make my own robot in gazebo (a diff-drive with a laser and a kinect) I wrote the following `urdf`:

https://github.com/schizzz8/lucrezio_simulation_environments/blob/master/urdf/lucrezio_with_logical.urdf.xacro

Now, I'd like to call `gazebo_msgs/GetLinkState` service to retrieve the pose of the sensor with respect to the gazebo world.

If I do that, that's the output I get:

[image: image description]

In fact, in the gazebo window, the robot seems to be made of just few links:

[image: image description]

How can I have gazebo to see also `camera_link` in order to retrieve its pose?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19607/how-to-call-gazebo_msg/getlinkstate-service-for-a-sensor-mounted-on-a-robot?/) by [federico.nardi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3295/federico.nardi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I see you have a lot of fixed joints on your URDF. When converted to SDF, links connected by fixed joints are lumped together into links for performance, and as a consequence, the link names change.

One thing you could try would be to use the `preserveFixedJoint` on your URDF, so that the fixed joints are persisted, and link names and poses don't change, for example:

```
<joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
...
</joint> 
<gazebo reference='camera_joint'>"
    <preserveFixedJoint>true</preserveFixedJoint>"
</gazebo>"
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [federico.nardi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3295/federico.nardi/) on 2018-06-06**:
I tried your solution, but nothing changes. Btw, I pushed the fix to the repo so you can check if I'm doing that right. To test it, you can run: roslaunch lucrezio_simulation_environments robot.launch (now the urdf is lucrezio.urdf.xacro)

**Comment by [federico.nardi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3295/federico.nardi/) on 2018-06-06**:
Of course, if I change the joint type to "continuous" then I can see it. My question is: is that  a possible solution? In the end, if I'm guaranteed that no one moves camera, I can be fine with this hack.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-06-06**:
I think you may be using an older version of Gazebo which doesn't support the preserve tag... In any case, using a revolute joint with zero limits should work fine even if it is moved.